# Custom input doesn't get a props value

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-state

So, i have a custom Input component that is created with react-hooks-form. It can have an initialvalue if it has such prop. In main form i fetch data and set it into a state. I want to pass that state as a prop to set the values into the input, but it does not work, sometimes a value that came is undefined, sometimes it has a value, but it does not set the value of an input.
Code of an input:

```
const Input = ({register, name, label, errors, initialValue}) => {
  const {setValue} = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(name, initialValue)
  }, [initialValue, name, setValue])

  return (
    <div className={`input`} >
      <label>{label}</label>
      <input
        {...register(name, {required: "This field is required!", minLength:{
          value: 5,
          message: "The field must be at least 5 characters"
          }})}
      />
      {errors[name] && <span>{errors[name].message}</span>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The code of a form that fetches data:

```
const FormTest = (props) => {
  const {register, handleSubmit, formState: {errors}} = useForm();
  const [title, setTitle] = useState();
  const [description, setDescription] = useState();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${random}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      setTitle(data.title);
      setDescription(data.body);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="form-wrapper">
      <h2 className="form-header">TEST</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Input
          name="title"
          label="Title"
          register={register}
          errors={errors}
          initialValue={title}
        />
        <Input
          name="description"
          label="description"
          register={register}
          errors={errors}
          initialValue={description}
        />
        <input type="submit"/>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your `useState` hooks don't have a default value set to them, so they would return `undefined` before fetch is resolved. Try to set a default value for them like `useState('default value')`

Comment: Adding values to states didn't change anything, the input values are still empty

Answer (score -1):

I can't see `handleSubmit` function in your code. You have called handleSubmit and passing onSubmit as a argument to that function. So I think issue lies there

Comment: `handleSubmit` is coming from the `useForm` hook. That is how it is intended to be used.